# regular expression for character that is not letter, number, new line or |

Tags: regex

Can anyone supply the regular expression for finding any character that is not letter, number new line or | the vertical line (that I don't know the name of )

I have lots of lines of text that is like this

```
929|10|10|1||S|N|||||||N|N|
```

And I want to find the odd character

Comment: The `|` is called a pipe. Or sometimes "vertical bar", but that's a bit clumsy :). So what exactly do you want to find in this string? All characters are letters, new lines or pipes. Also, which language or tool do you need the regex for? And lastly, what have you tried?

Comment: no `language tag`..that definitely doesn't help..

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It regexs are language agnostic aren't they ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky implementation of regex differs from language to language..for example:`javascript` doesnt support `negative lookbehinds` where as `java` supports it to some extent while `.net`supports it fully

Comment: then there are differences in the methods that are used to `find`,`replace`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're talking about is a "character class".

A character class is something like `[a-f]` which means letter `a`, `b` or `c`.

Putting a `^` at the beginning is the negation of that.

So you want `[^\da-zA-Z\n|]`.

The vertical line is called "pipe" or "vertical bar".

Answer (score 1):

> regular expression for character that is not letter, number, new line
>   or |

```
[^a-zA-Z\d\n|]
```

> I want to find the character that don't fit the criteria

Use `[^a-zA-Z\d\n|]` and iterate through the matches you find till the end..

> I want to find the odd character

`.(.)`

`$1` contains the odd character..just keep on iterating for all the other odd characters

Comment: I think by "odd character" he means "character that doesn't fit the criteria," not "every alternate character."

Comment: How did you manage to answer this question 8 seconds after it was asked?

Answer (score 0):

single character, not digits, pipes, or newline.

```
[^\da-zA-Z|\n]
```

Comment: \w = word characters (letters, digits, and underscores)